# Style hover effect in gridview - ASP.NET

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio, responsive-design

```
.gv_header
{
    background-color:#0033CC;   
    color:White;
}

.gv tr:hover 
{
   background-color:#0034CD;
   color:Yellow;
 }

<asp:GridView ID="gv_asig" runat="server"  CssClass="gv" >
   .....
   <HeaderStyle CssClass="gv_header" />
   <FooterStyle CssClass="gv_footer" />   

</asp:GridView>
```

How to retain the white letters when i hover the headers?, instead of becoming yellow too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do more specific your css to keep it white, add this after the `.gv tr:hover`

```
.gv .gv_header:hover {
   color:#fff;
}
```